# How to know if a setter exists

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

How can I know, trying to access dynamically, if a given setter exists for an object, assuming a getter does exist. So the point is to know if a value can be set for that property, but using `hasOwnProperty` returns true as a property by that name does exist.

Comment: `describeType(object)..accessor.(@name == "propName").@access != "readonly"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ram it with blunt front attack, but there's no telling if this corrupts the property data (in case there's a pre-processing setter):

```
try
{
    obj.propertyName = obj.propertyName
    trace("Setter is avaliable!");
}
catch (fail:Errot)
{
    trace("There's no setter...");
}
```

Alternately, use http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#describeType(), it seems that **< accessor >** tag is what you want.